# How get item by position from RecyclerView ListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I have a `RecyclerView` of custom objects which uses custom ListAdapter. Is there a way to get the position of Item in Adapter from Activity or how can I access the containing list?

Comment: What do you want to get exactly, the current item by position of the recyclerView?

Comment: As far as I know a `RecyclerView` comes with your corresponding `ListAdapter`. That one should contain your `onBindViewHolder` which gives you the position and content of every list entry. See this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java

Comment: Use interface in your Adapter class to get callback from your adapter.

Comment: Would you provide your `ListAdapter`?

Comment: I need to find the position of an object in adapter for scrolling to that position.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the position of Item in Adapter from Activity or how can I access the containing list?

You need to declare a method inside your custom list adapter that exposes the underlying list you provide on the constructor.

Something like this:

```
List<MyItem> myList = new List<MyItem>()
MyCustomListAdapter mAdapter = new MyCustomListAdapter(myList);
```

In MyCustomListAdapter constructor assign your list to a field `mInternalList` and declare a method:

```
public List<MyItem> getInternalList(){
    return mInternalList;
}
```

After this you can use all list utility methods to retrieve the index of an element.

Comment: I knew about that solution but I thought that there may be a nicer solution. In that case there is no sense of using ListAdapter instead of RecyclerView.Adapter,